# Creating unique pairs from a list of particles

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I already have code where I make unique pairs of proton and neutrons which are stored in the lists self.p and self.n respectively. I would also like to get unique pairs of protons and unique pairs of neutrons from these two lists.

Code to make proton-neuteron pairs:

```
 for proton in self.p:
            for neutron in self.n:
                self.pn_combinations.append([proton, neutron])
```

I cannot simply iterate twice over self.p to create unique pairs of protons, as list will contain duplicates and same set pairs just in reversed order. So I am not sure how to proceed.

E.g. self.p can contain 3 particles of:

```
self.p =  [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

And would like to output:

```
Pairs = [[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]],[[1, 2, 3, 4],[9,10,11,12]], [[5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]]
```

where each item in pairs is a unique combination of protons in self.p

Answer (score 2):

You may just treat each `particles` as an element and use `itertools.combinations()`

```
from itertools import combinations
p =  [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
pairs = [list(combination) for combination in combinations(p, 2)]
print(pairs)
```

output: `[[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], [[1, 2, 3, 4], [9, 10, 11, 12]], [[5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]]`

Comment: If pairs in tuples are acceptable, it does not even need the list comprehension, just `list(combinations(p, 2))`

Comment: @progmatico, yes, but since OP's example of the output contains the pairs in list, I adjusted the output according to his need.

Comment: Sure, actually my fault, it is explicitly asked!

Comment: Perfect, thanks for both of your contributions! also very succinct so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second loop from one index up then the outer loop is in:

```
p =  [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

particels = []
for i, part in enumerate(p):
    for part2 in p[i+1:]:
        particels.append( (part ,part2) )

print(particels)
```

Output:

```
[([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]), 
 ([1, 2, 3, 4], [9, 10, 11, 12]), 
 ([5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12])]
```

Comment: Oh perfect, works as intended, so many thanks.